# Number of students who study both Hindi and English

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, inclusion-exclusion

> In a survey of $100$ students, the number of students studying the various languages is found as: English only $18; $ English but not Hindi $23; $ English and Chinese $8;$ Chinese and Hindi $8;$ English $26;$ Chinese $48$ and no language $24.$ Find

> $(1)$ How many students are studying Hindi?

> $(2)$ How many students are studying both English and Hindi?

Let $U$ be the universal set. Then $n(U)=100$

And $E: $English and $H: $Hindi and $C: $ Chinese

Then $\displaystyle n(E\cap H'\cap H')=n(E)-n(E\cap H)-n(E\cap C)+n(E\cap H\cap C)=18$

$\displaystyle n(E\cap H')=n(E\cap H'\cap C')+n(E\cap C)-n(E\cap C\cap H)=23$ and $n(E\cap C)=8$ and $n(C\cap H)=8$ and $n(E)=26 ,n(C)=48$ and

$\displaystyle n(E'\cap C'\cap H')=n(U)-n(E\cup H\cup C)=24$

From the above data, we get $n(E\cap H)=n(E\cap H\cap C)$ and $n(E\cup H \cup C)=76$

Now using $\displaystyle n(E\cup H\cup C)=n(E)+n(H)+n(C)-n(E\cap H)-n(E\cap C)-n(H\cap C)+n(E\cap H\cap C)$

$\displaystyle 76=26+48+n(H)-8-8\Longrightarrow n(H)=18$

Now how can I find part $(2)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three languages involved: Chinese, English and Hindi.

I would like to divide all the $100$ students into eight groups, any two of which do not overlap.

Suppose:

- $n(C' \cap E' \cap H') = a_0$.
- $n(C' \cap E' \cap H) = a_1$.
- $n(C' \cap E \cap H') = a_2$.
- $n(C' \cap E \cap H) = a_3$.
- $n(C \cap E' \cap H') = a_4$.
- $n(C \cap E' \cap H) = a_5$.
- $n(C \cap E \cap H') = a_6$.
- $n(C \cap E \cap H) = a_7$.

We learn:

- $a_2 = 18$.
- $a_2 + a_6 = 23$, which means that $a_6 = 5$.
- $a_6 + a_7 = 8$, which means that $a_7 = 3$.
- $a_5 + a_7 = 8$, which means that $a_5 = 5$.
- $a_2 + a_3 + a_6 + a_7 = 26$, which means that $a_3 = 0$.
- $a_4 + a_5 + a_6 + a_7 = 48$, which means that $a_4 = 35$.
- $a_0 = 24$.
- $a_0 + a_1 + \dots + a_7 = 100$, which means that $a_1 = 10$.

Hence

- $n(C' \cap E' \cap H') = 24$.
- $n(C' \cap E' \cap H) = 10$.
- $n(C' \cap E \cap H') = 18$.
- $n(C' \cap E \cap H) = 0$.
- $n(C \cap E' \cap H') = 35$.
- $n(C \cap E' \cap H) = 5$.
- $n(C \cap E \cap H') = 5$.
- $n(C \cap E \cap H) = 3$.

---

(1) We learn from the list above that there are $10 + 0 + 5 + 3 = 18$ students who study Hindi.

(2) We learn from the list above that there are $0 + 3 = 3$ students who study both Chinese and Hindi.

Comment: An alternative notation would be to use capital letters to indicated inclusion and lower case for exclusion. E.g. ECh is the number of people studying English and Chinese but not Hindi.

Comment: @Acccumulation You are right; typing strings like `n(C \cap E \cap H')` is indeed not as easy as typing strings like `CEh`. I just used the notation which was used by the user who raised the question.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an image and slightly different explanation to Feather Wing's answer.

1. We have the amount of students who only study English being $18$,
   and the amount of students who study both Chinese and English being $8$.
   Combining those two groups result in the group with
   people who study English without studying Hindi combined with people who study all three languages, which is $18+8=26$ people.
2. Also, the amount of people who study English without studying Hindi is $23$.
3. This means that the amount of people who study all three languages is $26-23=3$.
4. This means that the amount of people who study both Chinese and English without studying Hindi is $8-3=5$.
5. Since the total number of people who study English is $26$, and the total number of people who study English without Hindi is $23$, we have **the total number of people who study both English and Hindi being $\boldsymbol{26-23=3}$**, which is the answer to the second part.
6. We know that the total amount of people who study English is $26$, and the total amount of people who study Chinese is $48$, and the amount of people who study both Chinese and English is $8$, so the amount of people who study both Chinese and English in total is $26+48-8=66$.
7. As there are $100$ people in total and $24$ people who do not study a language, $100-24=76$ people study a language.
8. This means there are $76-66=10$ people who study only Hindi.
9. Therefore, **there is a total of $\boldsymbol{10+0+3+5=18}$ people who study Hindi**, which is the answer to the first part.

[image]

Comment: Nice picture. Drawing the Venn diagram is the way to intuitively understand what you need to compute here.